# Error en el Where de mi consulta SQL Sequelize

Tags: javascript, nodejs, typescript, postgresql, sequelize.js

Hola amigos tengo un error en el where y no se como solucionarlo, tengo el siguiente codigo.

```
  const potentialValidate: any = await RulesProductModel.findAll({
            attributes: ['AllowPermanence'],
            where: {
                rpoMin: { [Op.gte]: 56 },
                rpoMax: { [Op.lte]: 58 },
                [Op.or]: [
                    { districtId: { [Op.eq]: 366 } },
                    { districtId: { [Op.is]: null } },
                ],
            },
        });
```

ye me da el siguiente error en el where:

```
Type '{ rpoMin: { [OpTypes.gte]: number; }; rpoMax: { [OpTypes.lte]: number; }; [OpTypes.or]: ({ districtId: { [OpTypes.eq]: number; }; } | { districtId: { [OpTypes.is]: null; }; })[]; }' is not assignable to type 'WhereOptions<RulesProduct> | undefined'.
  Types of property '[Op.or]' are incompatible.
    Type '({ districtId: { [OpTypes.eq]: number; }; } | { districtId: { [OpTypes.is]: null; }; })[]' is not assignable to type 'AllowArray<AllowNotOrAndWithImplicitAndArrayRecursive<Fn | Literal | Where | Json | WhereAttributeHash<RulesProduct>>> | undefined'.
      Type '{ districtId: { [OpTypes.is]: null; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Fn | Literal | Where | Json | WhereAttributeHash<RulesProduct> | { [OpTypes.or]: AllowArray<AllowNotOrAndWithImplicitAndArrayRecursive<Fn | Literal | Where | Json | WhereAttributeHash<...>>>; } | { ...; } | { ...; }'.
        Types of property 'districtId' are incompatible.
          Type '{ [OpTypes.is]: null; }' is not assignable to type 'WhereAttributeHashValue<number | undefined>'.
            Types of property '[Op.is]' are incompatible.
              Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Literal | undefined'.
```

Ya he probado muchas cosas incluso Op.and y no logro solucionar

Comment: Algo confuso el mensaje de error, pero entiendo que te dice que no puedes buscar algo con valor `null` cuando los valores son algún tipo de dato y `undefined`, probaste cambiando a buscar `undefined` en lugar de `null`?